# Element is not attached to the page document error in Python Script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script in Python with Selenium and I have a little problem extracting data from the Booking website after completing mandatory fields to cand see the offers.

I have this first script where I extract the data from the internet:

```
    def report_results(self):
    hotel_boxes = self.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="property-card"]')

    report = BookingReport(hotel_boxes)
    collections = report.pull_data()
    table = PrettyTable(field_names=["Hotel Name", "Score", "Price", "Address", "Distance"])
    table.add_rows(collections)
    print(table)
```

And here I have the BookingReport class where I am calling the "pull data" method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class BookingReport:
  def __init__(self, boxes_section_element:WebElement):
    self.boxes_section_element = boxes_section_element

def pull_data(self):
    try:
        collection = []

        for box in self.boxes_section_element:
            hotel_name = box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="title"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
            hotel_score = box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="review-score"] > div').get_attribute('innerHTML')
            hotel_price = box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-testid="price-and-discounted-price"]').get_attribute('innerHTML').replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
            hotel_address = box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-testid="address"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
            hotel_location = box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[data-testid="distance"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
            collection.append([ hotel_name, hotel_score, hotel_price, hotel_address, hotel_location ])
        return collection
    except Exception as e:
        print("There is a problem pulling data from the results: " + str(e))
```

And my self.boxes_section_element looks like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="d342d07a-4b36-404e-9cee-a781d65c1941")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="2f41c5d2-be66-4538-8862-08d67ae2ddb8")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="3bd24fcf-2aa4-46c1-a187-ae84d7dd345b")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="e9c3c41c-3e9a-4af0-a086-1efd362f82c8")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="b71f711d-81bc-4794-a78b-30b75b1931f9")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="7ca4740c-6f0c-4918-86d9-185a451f276e")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="8debf234-0078-4276-9dde-965cd2155256")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="b0aed7d1-f569-4f54-aee4-9c05d1e3009f")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="0efb210b-f63b-4b74-bf96-9152abbf4fd0")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="b717c166-6a61-4a8d-aaca-3b5050e3e26f")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="8181d414-e810-4d7a-a989-0f8619f5e322")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="c5225ff7-ddda-4f0a-8948-99c8f55f57bc")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="47c9f7dc-9ac9-46f3-a36f-bda77b2ec2cd")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="c3ece8d6-b8f4-4a06-9ee0-7629e6b7251d")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="cb6cb8c5-b2bb-4cbe-a7cf-b83c45289939")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="d4b2f50b-b03b-4a7d-9554-51db95c2c762")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="824727a5-b0b3-475f-a6fc-166d2461b2e6")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="809f0a31-b4ab-4548-9161-c06ad041d53c")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="849cfe2f-1379-4a43-aa76-69b29c5248cc")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="e55597af-6297-4a61-8fff-61758c3693f8")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="beaf7c9b-7162-4a10-872b-7e79b38a28ab")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="823e44d3-bc11-49f6-9b63-22bc3a7a6e51")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="160d0563-5bdd-4675-9068-d294225dc284")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="9cad63bd-8fd2-4774-920c-827a329e63d6")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="306caa33cb10250f0bab57c7e029a054", element="bb7cfa2a-af25-4fc7-b59b-75f65417c352")>
```

And my problem is:

```
There is a problem running this program from command line interface: Message: target frame detached
(failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer)
(Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.86)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FFDCE3+50899]
    (No symbol) [0x00F8E111]
    (No symbol) [0x00E95450]
    (No symbol) [0x00E88197]
    (No symbol) [0x00E86F06]
    (No symbol) [0x00E8778A]
    (No symbol) [0x00E906F5]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9ACF8]
    (No symbol) [0x00EEE18F]
    (No symbol) [0x00EDB6F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00EB7708]
    (No symbol) [0x00EB886D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01263EAE+2566302]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012992B1+2784417]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0129327C+2759788]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01095740+672048]
    (No symbol) [0x00F98872]
    (No symbol) [0x00F941C8]
    (No symbol) [0x00F942AB]
    (No symbol) [0x00F871B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x752E0099+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77267B6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77267B3E+238]

There is a problem running this program from command line interface: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How should I fix it?